# PHP exec command node

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm running Apache and Node.js on the same server.
I tried to execute this command using PHP:

```
exec('usr/bin/node', 'var/www/html/app/node/server.js');
var_dump($output);
```

It returned:

```
"array(0) {}";
```

Do you have any idea why PHP did not execute the command node?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For other people (as answer below helped), also check if exec is allowed, and if not targeting an owned binary you'd need something like suphp

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute paths:

`exec('/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/app/node/server.js', $output);`

`usr/bin/node` is a relative path meaning it will appended to the current directory php script is executed in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I tried using the absolute path '/usr/bin/node', but it does not work.
I feel that the command node is not recognized .

Do you have another idea ?

Comment: Amended my answer. Try the it now.

Comment: exec('/usr/bin/node /var/www/html/app/node/server.js  2>&1', $output);
2>&1 For debug ;)